# How to prevent Keycloak from creating default Clients in new Realm?

Tags: client, keycloak

It is possible to prevent Keycloak from creating default Clients (e.g. account, account-console, admin-cli) in the new Realm? I init my Keycloak from `realm-export.json` using Docker.

I removed default Clients from `realm-export.json` and add own, but the result is both exist in Realm.

Answer (score 1):

It's essential for Keycloak that you don't remove the built-in default clients. It may cause exceptions on some points.

If you don't need them, just disable them, but don't delete!

Comment: is it true for KK 18.0.0+ ? 2022 is not a year for "you see the button, but you can't"...